# Cannot get simple Jquery .addclass to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking at these questions such as these below.

[How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)
[jQuery addClass not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188184/jquery-addclass-not-working)

Yet I cannot seem to get this to work in wordpress.

I create a myscript.js and add this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addhere').addClass('well');
})
```

Then I en queued it in my functions.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

I also did the add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );, I know that works as I have included bootstrap.min.js which works correctly.

I am trying to add it here,

```
<nav id="addhere" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

**Just to test so i can see if it worked.**

My question is what am I doing wrong? Why will it not add the class?

Comment: How have you determined that it's not working? Have you verified that the script is actually running?

Comment: Also verify if `$('#addhere').length` is 0.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Jquery I know that the script is loaded, How do I tell if it is running?

Comment: Is nav a valid html tag? Did you include jQuery library?

Comment: Yes Jquery library is added as bootstrap requires it.

Comment: @user3558931 [html nav](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

Comment: @merlin Sorry why would I need to verify the .length?

Comment: @jackdh: It's called debugging. You eliminate possible reasons for failure. If the element you're selecting wasn't found, the `.length` of the jQuery object will be `0`.

Comment: Check browser's console for errors.

Comment: @merlin sorry still new to this, I used the .length function, how do I tell what the output was/is? I looked in the console but did not see anything, although I did have a Uncaught typeError: undefinedis not a function:

Comment: @jackdh First, `.length` is not a function. Second, Find the line number of the `Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function` and see which function is undefined.

Comment: did you actually include jQuery? The Code-Snippet only tells that, bootstrap js depends on jQuery, but did you actually include it? If so, please show us how, and where I would think that jQuery (`$`) is actually undefined, because not included.

Comment: @jackdh to verify if it's running, do a alert("blah"), this would at least ensure you enter the $(document).ready() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up `jQuery(..)` and `$(..)`.

Im not sure if that would actually work, so try this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#addhere').addClass('well');
});
```

It seems that if you load jQuery imlicitly over wordpress, it is beeing loaded in no conflict-mode (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) as this [blog post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) states.

Comment: Brilliant that second one worked. Although I am not sure why would you mind explaining?